# quering a database inside a websocket server

Tags: php, ajax, websocket

I'm currently working on a web app, I'm working on a chat app feature. I want to create a real-time chat feature that uses websockets, and phpwebsocket as ws server, i want the chats to be logged in a database, my question is, which one of the following will be the best practice in terms of user experience and web server performance:

1. whenever a clients sends a message, the message is first sent to the server via ajax and a script does the necessary processing and logs it to the database, then return true, then on success it return information back to the client, then a callback function sends the message to the websocket server and the server just relays it to the recipient.
2. whenever the client sends a message, the message is sent to the websocket server and the websocket does the processing and posting to the database then on success it relays the message to the recipient.

My concern of the second option is putting too much load on the websocket server, since it is a single script serving different clients.....Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the chat solution, websockets seems the better approach as long as you understand that you have limited IE support (IE9 cannot do websockets).

Now, about your concern, it would be a nice scenario to run a poC, but as a recommendation, I think that the performance will be similar in both scenarios as it will be handled by the app server. If it turns out that the DB access is an issue, you can still come to some solution like put the messages on some sort of async queue and have some separate process write them to the database. This will only work if the successful DB write is not critical or needed for the response.

Comment: Thank you for your response, if i may ask how can i go about putting messages in an async queue, an example will be appreciated. thanks again

Comment: Hi, first of all I would start with a volume study. The queueing would only be advisable if you have any performance issues, but it would be the same risk as if you use a ajax request. Here's an example of what you could do with PHP: http://www.ebrueggeman.com/blog/creating-a-message-queue-in-php

Comment: Thanx Martin, that my come handy, I'll take your advice and doa volume study first. Your help is appreciated